# ¿Como deserealizar este json en vb.net?

Tags: json, vb.net, facebook-api

estoy utilizando la api Graph de Facebook con webhook para canalizar un mensaje entrante de una pagina en mi aplicación. La respuesta recibida de la API es la siguiente:

```
{   "object":"page",
    "entry": [{"id":"594052300785675",
            "time":1495551653413,
            "messaging":[{
                "sender": {"id":"1501979286539065"},
                "recipient":{"id":"594052300785675"},
                "timestamp":1495551624095,
                "message":{
                    "mid":"mid.$cAAJGvf9bkd5iZxgLn1cNdDAgNL_l",
                    "seq":505,
                    "text":"HOLA HOLA HOLA POKEMO GOKU DRAGON BALL"
                    }
                }]
        }]
}
```

¿Como puedo obtener el dato **text** para despues guardarlo en mi base de datos?
Estoy utilizando framework 4.0  de vb.net

Comment: lo recibes como objeto?? como texto??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente :

```
Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(strJson);
```

Donde `strJson` es lo que obtienes de la api

Y luego recorrerlo

```
For Each Row In json("entry")
    //Row("messaging")
Next
```

Y recorrer sus propiedades

Comment: Muchas Gracias, es lo que necesitaba. No te puedo votar porque no tengo reputacion. Pero me sirvio. Saludos!

Comment: me alegro que te haya ayudado!, recuerda que si para otra vez que recibas un JSON, lo mejor es crear una clase con todas las propiedades que necesites y deserealizarlo como objeto!, es mas facil el tratamiento. Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Aunque ya hay una respuesta aceptada, como parece que todavía hay gente que no lo conoce voy a explicar dos formas de crear clases para deserializar JSON.

**Opcion A**

Hay diferentes opciones online, por ejemplo [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)(para c#). Simplemente pegar el json de ejemplo, pulsar <kbd>Generate</kbd> y listo

**Opcion B**

En el Visual Studio existe una opción desde hace varias versiones para autogenerar clases tanto para json como para XML. Es muy sencillo. Copiamos el json/xml de ejemplo, y vamos a `Editar`,`Pegado Especial`,`Pegar JSON como clases` y automáticamente se generar las clases necesarias.

Cogiendo como ejemplo el JSON de la pregunta, este es el resultado:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property _object As String
    Public Property entry() As Entry
End Class

Public Class Entry
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property time As Long
    Public Property messaging() As Messaging
End Class

Public Class Messaging
    Public Property sender As Sender
    Public Property recipient As Recipient
    Public Property timestamp As Long
    Public Property message As Message
End Class

Public Class Sender
    Public Property id As String
End Class

Public Class Recipient
    Public Property id As String
End Class

Public Class Message
    Public Property mid As String
    Public Property seq As Integer
    Public Property text As String
End Class
```

Comment: Yo voto a favor tuyo, solo que en este caso en particular no era un objeto lo que el recibia, por eso le aconseje tambien que para otras ocaciones, creara clases y las trabajara asi, de todas formas +1 para tu aporte!

Comment: @sioesi Yo tambien voté tu respuesta, ya que es totalmente correcta. Pero como de vez en cuando aparecen preguntas de este tipo y muchos no saben como generar las clases, me pareció util añadir la mia.