# ¿Cómo hacer este esquema JSON usando JSON.net?

Tags: c#, json, .net

Estoy tratando de serializar el siguiente esquema Json utilizando la librería Json.NET:

```
{
  "Lista": [
    {
      "codigo": "112233",
      "nombre": "Mr Holmes",
      "tipo": "C",
      "nit": "SHRLK221B",
      "origen": "000002",
      "destino": "000001",
      "importador": "Y",
      "Origen": "2",
      "ubicacion": "2",
      "listadedireccion": [
        {
          "direcion": "000001",
          "linea": 123,
          "calle": "Bakers 221B",
          "pais": "London",
          "ciuda": "City"
        },
        {
          "direcion": "000001",
          "linea": 123,
          "calle": "Bakers 221B",
          "pais": "London",
          "ciuda": "City"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Esta es mi clase objecto:

```
public class Listadedireccion
    {
        public string direcion { get; set; }
        public int linea { get; set; }
        public string calle { get; set; }
        public string pais { get; set; }
        public string ciuda { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lista
    {
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string tipo { get; set; }
        public string nit { get; set; }
        public string origen { get; set; }
        public string destino { get; set; }
        public string importador { get; set; }
        public string Origen { get; set; }
        public string ubicacion { get; set; }
        public IList<Listadedireccion> listadedireccion { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public IList<Lista> Lista { get; set; }
    }
```

Pero cunado trato de serializar el Json no logro llenar el array listadedireccion alguna sugerencia? este es mi código actual:

```
  List<Lista> list = new List<Lista>() { new Lista()
        {       "codigo"= "112233",
  nombre= "Mr Holmes",
  tipo= "C",
  nit= "SHRLK221B",
  origen= "000002",
  destino= "000001",
  importador= "Y",
  Origen= "2",
  ubicacion"= "2",
  listadedireccion
        },


        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            Lista = list
        });
```

como puedo continuar el llenado del nodo listadedireccion he intentado instanciarlo de varias maneras pero no funciona

Comment: Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/72406/15301) que di hace un tiempo sobre como crear clases de serializacion json en visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

He utilizado tus clases **Lista** y **Listadedireccion**, para no repetirlas aquí.

Te pongo aquí el ejemplo de cómo lo he llenado:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ListaEjemploStack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListaEjemplo listaEjemplo = new ListaEjemplo()

            {
                codigo = "Algun Codigo",
                destino = "Algun Destino",
                Listadedireccion = new List<Listadedireccion>()
                {
                    new Listadedireccion()
                    {
                        calle ="Mi Calle",
                        pais ="Algun Pais"
                    }
                }
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaEjemplo);

            ListaEjemplo listaDeserealizada = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListaEjemplo>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(listaDeserealizada.Listadedireccion.First().pais);
        }
    }
}
```

NO he tenido ningún inconveniente para serializar y deserealizar. Quizás mi única recomendación es que tengas en cuenta que: **Listadedireccion** es un *objeto complejo*.
Es decir que tiene que estar *creado* para ser agregado como parte de la lista.
En mi ejemplo hago el **new** de la lista llamada *ListaDireccion* pero tambien hago el **new** del primer elemento que compone dicha lista. Es decir, creo la lista y también creo el elemento que forma parte de ella.

**Nota**: trataría de evitar llamar, al menos en este caso, las propiedades igual que el nombre de la clases para que te sea menos dificil darte cuenta.

```
public IList<Listadedireccion> listadedireccion { get; set; }
```

En lo personal lo llamaría *Direcciones* y por ser propiedad la Primer Letra en Mayúscula:

```
public IList<Listadedireccion> Direcciones { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

Te comento a mi parecer para que obtengas el resultado esperado:

```
public class Listadedireccion
{
    /* así como está en tu código */
}

public class Lista
{
    /* así como está en tu código */

    /* Agrega connstructor */
    public Lista() { List<Listadedireccion> listadedireccion = new List<Listadedireccion>();  }
    /* Personalmente prefiero usar List que IList */
}
```

*Toda vez que es el patrón actualmente en uso te lo pongo como lo he usado en MVC*

```
public JsonResult obtenerRespuestaJson() 
{
    List<Lista> miLista = new List<Lista>();

    /* El proceso necesario para llenar "miLista" */
    /* Ejemplo de como sería */
    Lista nuevoElemento = new Lista();
    /* Asignas valor a cada propiedad */
    /* Igual a listadedireccion; como desde el constructor ya esta inicializada basta empeza a llenarla */
    Listadedireccion unaNuevaDreccion = new Listadedireccion(); // Un dato a la vez
    nuevoElemento.listadedireccion.Add(unaNuevaDreccion );
    /* etc, etc por cada nuevo "Lista" que conformara "miLista" */
    // Agregamos
    miLista.Add(nuevoElemento); // Tanto o tantas veces como necesites

    return Json(new { Lista = miLista  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
} // obtenerRespuestaJson
```

Espero te sea de utilidad o al menos ilustrativo.

*No encontre que es "BPList" por tal razón no lo inclui*

Comment: me arroja System.NullReferenceException cunado trato de agregar  el elemnto de dirección:  nuevoElemento.listadedireccion.Add(unaNuevaDreccion);

Comment: Sinceramente no encuentro que lo puede genera.