# como deserealizar el siguiente json en c#

Tags: c#

```
     {
        "language": "es",
        "textAngle": 0,
        "orientation": "Up",
        "regions": [
            {
               "boundingBox": "1,135,224,84",
               "lines": [
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "2,135,222,21",
                       "words": [
                          {
                        "boundingBox": "2,135,173,21",
                        "text": "MINISTERIO"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "191,136,33,19",
                        "text": "DE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "boundingBox": "1,163,224,29",
                "words": [
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1,163,224,29",
                        "text": "HACIENDA"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "boundingBox": "1,207,224,12",
                "words": [
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1,207,64,12",
                        "text": "DIRECCION"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "70,207,53,12",
                        "text": "GENERAL"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "127,207,14,12",
                        "text": "DE"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "146,207,79,12",
                        "text": "TRIBUTACION"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
       }
      ]
   }
```

con este codigo obtuve las regiones :

```
      Jsons region= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Jsons>(response.Content);
            List<Region> regiones = region.regions;
```

pero como accedo a las lines y luego a los words?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es usar

http://json2csharp.com/

para obtener la class equivalente a esa estructura

```
public class Word
{
    public string boundingBox { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
    public string boundingBox { get; set; }
    public List<Word> words { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public string boundingBox { get; set; }
    public List<Line> lines { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public int textAngle { get; set; }
    public string orientation { get; set; }
    public List<Region> regions { get; set; }
}
```

entonces usarias

```
 RootObject root= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
 List<Region> regiones = root.regions;
```

Comment: Por ampliar, como ya expliqué en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/72406/15301), no es necesario usar una herramienta externa si no se quiere, visual studio es capaz de crear las clases necesarias a partir de un json de ejemplo.