# capturar una cadena de caracteres aleatoria

Tags: c#, regex

Esta es mi situación:

Tengo una respuesta http de formato desconocido, solo sé que hay algo que se llama key y que puede tener cualquier pinta, no sé el número de caracteres ni si son mayúsculas, etc...

El caso es que he pensado que puedo coger el valor de key mediante regex.

Espero que la respuesta tenga el siguiente formato `"key": dfasdfasdf_654`, siendo dfasdfasdf_654 totalmente aleatorio.

He probado con `("key": [A-Z] )\w[]+` y con `("key": [A-Z] )` pero no es exactamente lo que quiero, ya que `[A-Z]` solo vale para un caracter, y yo necesito que sea para varios.

Comment: ¿ Como sabes donde termina el valor ? ¿ O es desde `key` hasta el final ?

Comment: espero que encontrar algo del tipo "key": llave , es decir, espero que termine en un espacio en blanco

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. Estamos hablando de un json? o es texto en plano? Crees que es necesario usar un regex?

Comment: si es un json, no hace falta un regex para capturarlo, puedes serializarlo si lo recibes como un string

Comment: @NicolasOñate, el problema es que no sé el como va a ser la clase de vuelta, la que recibo, entonces pensé sacar un string, y de ahi con todo sacar la key

Comment: sospecho que recibo un json, pero no lo tengo confirmado aun, no me han dado casi nada de informacion

Comment: Si es un json no es necesario complicarse la vida. Una libreria como json.net te permitira deserializar los datos sin problemas...

Comment: Si tenes un formato Json, como por ejemplo `"Clave" : Valor` puedes construir un modelo y rellenarlo, asi no tienes que complicarte como dice Pikoh, tengo un [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370450/estructura-json/370459#370459) de como realizarlo

Comment: el problema es que no sé cual es el modelo exactamente, solo se que tiene ciertos campos pero puede tener mas

Comment: Tampoco es problema Iria. Simplemente con un ejemplo del json, visual studio es capaz de generarte el modelo.

Comment: Con ciertos campos o mas, a que te refieres? si es un json con n valores con formato simple (`{"Nombre": "Valor"},{"Nombre1": "Valor2"}`) con hacer un modelo que tenga dos elementos que capturen el nombre y el valor lo solucionas, si es multidimensional es otra cosa

Comment: [Aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/72406/15301) explico como generar las clases automaticamente dado un ejemplo del json

Comment: el tema es que no tengo ni idea, no me han dicho si es multidimensional, no tengo control o conocimiento mas alla de lo que he puesto, asumo que es un json, no quiere decirque lo sea

Comment: ¿Cómo saber si es un JSON? sencillo, si los elementos están estructurados `"nombre": "valor"` es un json

Comment: ya, pero ahoramismo no puedo testear, esto va a live directo, asi que no tengo manera posible de saber si es un json o una url o no, asumo que es un json

Comment: A la pregunta le faltaria codigo, pero si no sabes lo que es.. y viene en un string, no necesitas una regex, necesitas un simple substr que extraiga la parte de la key y listo el tema...

Comment: *Una respuesta `http` de formato desconocido*. ¿Estamos en los inicios de la web? ¿O es que recibes respuestas de servidores anárquicos? ¿No usan cabecera `content-type`? El protocolo `http 1.1` establece en su [cláusula 7.2.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1) que toda respuesta que incluya una entidad tipo `body` ***debe*** incluir una cabecera `content-type`. En la respuesta `http` que recibes ¿no se incluye dicha cabecera?. Muy mal si es así. Saludos

Comment: Creo que se refiere a que no tiene el requerimiento completo, entonces sabe de ante mano que tiene que hacer pero no de forma completa, entonces se esta adelantando a eso. Podrías ver la pagina de Newtonsoft y ahi tienes ejemplos de todas las caracteristicas que uno a diario no usa y te pueden servir. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm

Answer (score 1):

Sin haberlo visto, apostaria a que no es tan 'aleatorio'. Tiene pinta de que la respuesta es un [JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) con algún atributo cuyo valor sea una cadena en [base64](https://base64.guru/learn/base64-characters).

De ser así, probaría a parsear el JSON ([aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c) se discuten alternativas) y así te podrías quedar con el valor de la key.

Si no es un JSON, podrías "parsear" el contenido via regex. Algo así debería funcionar (suponiendo que lo que tengas a continuación sea una cadena base64)

```
"key"\s*:\s*[A-Za-z0-9+/]+={0,2}
```

Si la key pudiera tener saltos de línea (algo posibles en codificaciones base64), utiliza esto en su lugar:

```
"key"\s*:\s*[A-Za-z0-9+/\r\n]+={0,2}
```